# jQuery Click - Doesn't work when page 1st loaded, but works if page is reloaded

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

I have an issue with the jQuery click function.  I am trying to integrate jQuery Mobile Autocomplete into an C# MVC application.

It the following code doesn't work when the page first loads.  However, it works if I reload/refresh the page.

HTML:

```
        <ul data-role="listview"  class="selectitems" data-filter="true"  data-inset="true" data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search Ingredients...">
            @foreach (var i in Model.ingredientList){
                <li data-id="@i.id" data-unit="@i.useUnit.symbol"><a href="#" class="ui-screen-hidden">@i.title</a></li>
            }
        </ul>
```

Script:

```
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.selectitems > li').on('click', function () {
            $('input[data-type="search"]').val($(this).text());
            $("ul:jqmData(role='listview')").children().addClass('ui-screen-hidden');
            $('#hdnIngredientID').val($(this).data('id'));
            $('#txtUseQtyDetails').val($(this).data('unit'));
            $('#hdnIngredientTitle').val($(this).text());
            $('#txtQty').focus();
        });

        $('.ui-input-clear').on('tap', function () {
            $('#hdnIngredientID').val('');
            $('#txtUseQtyDetails').val('');
        });
    });
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

jQuery-mobile autocomplete hides the list items until user input happens using CSS "display: none;".  Would this prevent the click function from being assigned?  If so, how do I work around this?

FURTHER UPDATE:

Found that the "live" function is depreciated.  Changed it to "on" instead.  Unfortunately this didn't fix the problem :-(

Could it be because the "li" items are hidden by CSS when the page is loaded?

I've deployed it here:

http://rar_mobile_dev.runarestaurant.com/Ingredient/Create?recipe_id=15240

(username: test, password: test)

Comment: Is this script inside a `$(function(){...})` block? You should try to attach events after the DOM is sone loading.

Comment: No, it's just by itself in <script> tags.

Comment: Tried put it into "$(document).ready(function ()", but same problem.

Comment: Might be a problem with the order your scripts get loaded in. Without being able to see it, there isn't much we can do. Is this deployed anywhere?

Comment: Tried reordering the scripts.  But it didn't work :-(

Answer (score -1):

You could try using on() in stead of click.

```
$(document).on('click', '.selectitems > li', function(){
        $('input[data-type="search"]').val($(this).text());
        $("ul:jqmData(role='listview')").children().addClass('ui-screen-hidden');
        $('#hdnIngredientID').val($(this).data('id'));
        $('#txtUseQtyDetails').val($(this).data('unit'));
        $('#hdnIngredientTitle').val($(this).text());
        $('#txtQty').focus();
});
```

Comment: This didn't work and got a "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'" error.